# find selector with specific content in mootools like this jquery selector

Tags: mootools

I need to convert this jquery to mootools.

```
$('tr[class$="-hours"]').css('display', 'none');


$$('XXX').setStyle('display', 'none');
```

does mootools 1.12 (my CMS has this version installed) have something like the selector above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MooTools [supports the W3C CSS3 Selectors](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars).

```
$$('tr[class$="-hours"]').setStyle('display', 'none');
```

Comment: @liz, ah, you should have mentioned the mootools version in your question. I'm not sure, but MooTools has supported CSS3 selectors for quite a while now. Have you actually tried the code in question?

Comment: lol. why do people first ask a question instead of just trying if it works? writing the question and waiting for answers sure takes longer than just writing the code and hitting reload.

Comment: well, i did that LOL and it didnt work. so then i wrote the message. then while i was waiting i tried it in jsfiddle and it worked. then i went back to my code and looked again and saw i had two sets of <script> tags in it ... and then it worked... and then i saw what you wrote...